# Can a HighWay Enforcer/Patrolmen remain in a Cross State Pursuit?

Tags: police, south-carolina

I kind of got this question in my mind as I saw a North Augusta Squad Car drive out of the city not responding to any emergency. Say a South Carolina HWP were to do a routing traffic stop and the person flees, They go into Georgia and then Alabama. Can the HWP unit remain in the pursuit or does he have to break off? Can he request to remain in the pursuit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Hot Pursuit

What you're describing is a hot pursuit, and in the US, common law says that police officers crossing state lines while in hot pursuit is absolutely allowed. An active pursuit is considered an exigent circumstance, which gives police all kinds of temporary powers they don't normally have.